# Why does npm install two different version of the same dependency when installed separately

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

## Scenario 1

**Terminal**: Windows `cmd`

**node version**: `v8.0.0`

**npm version**: `v5.5.1`

I have a `package.json` where I specifically mention

```
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.3.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-graph": "^4.3.0",
```

These have a subdependency on `d3-scale`.

In this scenario the `npm install` command installs `d3-scale: v2.0.0` which has `dist/` folder in it. (Note: I use `d3-scale/dist` in a `systemjs.config.js` file for an **Angular** App)

## Scenario 2

**Terminal**: Windows Subsystem For Linux (`bash for ubuntu for windows`)

**node version**: `v8.11.1`

**npm version**: `v5.6.0`

I perform `npm install` with the same `package.json` and this time it provides me with `d3-scale: v1.0.7` which has `build/` folder instead of `dist/` [quick comparison on d3-scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/compare/v1.0.7...master#diff-a084b794bc0759e7a6b77810e01874f2).

Now because of this discrepancy I had to change my `systemjs.config.js` to point to `build` for a local machine.

If the app gets deployed on the server or a cloud I am not sure which `d3-scale` it might download in the `node_modules` and I might have to commit a hotfix for it.

### Question

Why is there a discrepancy in the first place? What is causing this?

Comment: I think the best is, when you read the npm documentation about package lock files
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks
You could add the package-lock.json to your VCS, so every machine you working on or even your CI will use the right dependencies.

Comment: @Anditthas I already have a `package-lock.json` and it states that `d3-scale` uses `v1.0.7` but it still downloads `v2.0.0` when using `cmd`

Comment: I had a look at the npm change log, it seems that they resolved an issue in v5.6.0. >> Fully cross-platform package-lock.json. Installing a failing optional dependency on one platform no longer removes it from the dependency tree, meaning that package-lock.json should now be generated consistently across platforms! 
Here, you can read it yourself: https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.6.0. So try to upgrade your windows NPM to v5.6.0

Comment: super. Write that as an answer!

Comment: Thanks! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the NPM team resolved an issue in v5.6.0.

> Fully cross-platform package-lock.json. Installing a failing optional
>   dependency on one platform no longer removes it from the dependency
>   tree, meaning that package-lock.json should now be generated
>   consistently across platforms!

[Source](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.6.0)

So try to upgrade your windows NPM to v5.6.0. It should work now.